# Redmine custom fields on Projects page

Tags: redmine, percentage, redmine-plugins

I have recently setup Redmine and really like it. However, a feature which I really want is to set up Project completion in a percentage type facility (such as 5% 10% etc.) which is editable simply by the developer, not automated.

I know that you can create custom fields but something that I really want is that the column can show up on the "Homepage" / "Projects Page" to give a more detailed overview rather than going into each individual project.

Is there a way to do this with any plugins?

I am running Redmine 2.2.0

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put custom fields on the project list page (or need to search for third-party solution), but you do can customize custom fields to look as gauge bar using [Extended Fields](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/extended-fields/wiki/Custom-fields-view-customization) plugin.